# Direct2d duplicate/stretch 1px image

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d

If i have a 1px thick image How would i go about duplicating it so it becomes bigger, or how would i stretch it.

Because as you can see with my code its not the best looping `DrawImage`

```
    colorMatrixEffect->SetInput(0, texture); //texture = ID2D1Bitmap*
    D2D1_MATRIX_5X4_F matrix = D2D1::Matrix5x4F(color->r, 0, 0, 0, 0, color->g, 0, 0, 0, 0, color->b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    colorMatrixEffect->SetValue(D2D1_COLORMATRIX_PROP_COLOR_MATRIX, matrix);

    if (rect.right == 0)
    {
        device_context_d2d1->DrawImage(colorMatrixEffect.get(),
            D2D1::Point2F(newRect.left + offsetX, newRect.top + offsetY));
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(newRect.right); i++)
        {
            device_context_d2d1->DrawImage(colorMatrixEffect.get(),
                D2D1::Point2F(newRect.left + offsetX + i, newRect.top + offsetY));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To stretch the image you can use scaling transformation.

You can also render your image to `D2D1Bitmap` and draw it as a bitmap, there's `DrawBitmap` method with more parameters which allows you to draw any part of the bitmap to any part of the target device with stretching.

To draw repeated patterns you can create bitmap or image brush with `CreateBitmapBrush`/`CreateImageBrush` method and set `extendMode*` properties to `D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP` value and then just fill desired shape with this brush.